# RTMP/RTSP for integration in a Lift App

Tags: java, scala, lift, red5, rtmp

Is it possible to integrate the [Red5](https://code.google.com/p/red5) server in a [Lift](http://liftweb.net) app?

I want to serve media via RTMP/RTSP, but the requests would need some work for the app (to handle authorization). If I can't integrate Red5, what are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

A broad question. Well, Lift has REST: https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/REST_Web_Services

has StreamingResponse (to respond with a stream) http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html#toc-Subsection-9.4.2

And is written in Scala, so can use java code.

So, I'd say "Yes".